# How yolo-v5,v7 handles rectangular input?

Tags: yolo, yolov7

I recently noticed that yolo architecture can handle retangular inputs. specifically, your model can be trained on square images. But you can still export your model on a specified rectangular input size (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/issues/232)

However, I had a hard time to figure out how it works underneath (it doesn't seem like they just put some resize ops in).
Seeking some help to learn more about the mechanism

Thanks!!